# What is the "/.vol" directory for?

Tags: macos, mac, path, logical-drive

In Mac OS X, what is the `/.vol` directory for? I noticed that Excel usually reverences files (while investigating in instruments) using a `/.vol` path. Is it a folder for temporary files, or does it contain links to all files in the volume?

If so, how can I reference a file via its `/.vol` path?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per [this page about invisible files on Mac OS X](http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/invisibles.html):

> This pseudo-directory is used to
>   access files by their ID number (aka
>   inode number) rather than by name. For
>   example, /.vol/234881034/105486 is
>   file #105486 on volume #234881034.

You can find the volume id and inode using `stat`. An example, using `/etc/hosts`:

```
$ head -3 /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#

$ stat /etc/hosts
234881026 23347035 -rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 0 1035 "Jul 15 10:11:35 2010" "May 30 20:55:10 2010" "May 30 20:55:11 2010" "May 30 20:47:32 2010" 4096 8 0 /etc/hosts

$ head -3 /.vol/234881026/23347035
##
# Host Database
#
```

Comment: Just to explain, the first two numbers returned by `stat` are the volume ID and the inode.  `./vol` is used to access files by volume ID and inode.